# How to pass value outside the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to use a variable value that is created inside a function to outside of that function. but it is showing undefined. actually I am getting ip address using api and want to use that ip address outside the function. Inside function,its working fine but outside it alerts undefined. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userip;
    window.onload = function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.type = "text/javascript";

        script.src = "https://jsonip.com/?callback=DisplayIP";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    };
    function DisplayIP(response) {
        document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + response.ip;     
        userip  = response.ip;
        alert(userip);  // alerts  ip address
    }
alert(userip); // alerts undefined. it should alert ip address

</script>
```

Comment: You've to call the function in order to get the ip assigned to `userip`.

Comment: this is a sync issue. the alert outside of the `onload` function runs before all the stuff inside the function

Comment: If `DisplayIP` is called within the appended script, then Scrimothy's comment tells what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
var userip  = response.ip;
```

Get rid of `var` making it:

```
userip  = response.ip;
```

Beware, this makes it to the global scope. And it will be subjected to be accessed and modified by all. So, make sure you give a unique name.

Comment: yes, I also did that but same result. that why I used var

Comment: @Rizwi That's weird. Try completely getting rid of `var`.

Comment: Do you ever call `DisplayIP` to set the `userip`?

Comment: yes, DisplayIP is called and it is displaying ip inside function but not outside.

Comment: Well your code should show that then, because right now the last line of your code is trying to alert the value of a variable that has never been set.

Comment: you can check it on your end plz

Comment: This is ... an awful advice, do not follow.

Comment: @Teemu I did write the disclaimer.

Comment: But undeclared variables are bad in any circumstances, in the OP, the variable already is global, since it was declared in the global scope ...

Comment: @Teemu Agreed...

Comment: Well, it looks like Quentin has smelt something between the lines. Not my downvote, though.

Comment: @Teemu No worries. I know it was Quentin. `:P`

Answer (score 0):

Your code are executed in the same order it was written. Your script begin to request "https://jsonip.com/?callback=DisplayIP" at on load page, but your last "alert" are executed following your code order and at this time
"userip" has not a value. Its value is filled just when your request are finished. For this reason "alert" inside DisplayIP works and the last one not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var userip;
    window.onload = function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.type = "text/javascript";

        script.src = "https://jsonip.com/?callback=DisplayIP";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    };

    function DisplayIP(response) {
        document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + response.ip;     
        userip  = response.ip;
        alert(userip);
    }

    alert(userip);

    // Try this to understanding what I mean
    setInterval(_ => alert(userip), 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: you are right. so whats the solution?

Comment: Depend on what you intend. You can call some function after DisplayIP triggered. Could you provide some more details? Would you like to show this value in some input?

Comment: You can use variable userip in whole code since it's a global variable. But make sure execute the rest of your code after DisplayIP is triggered: function DisplayIP(response) { ... userip  = response.ip; someFunction(); }

Comment: can you check same question here and answer please? everything is explained here in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956954/how-to-get-ip-in-variable-using-javascript