# how to get ip in variable using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is an api that gives ip address.

```
https://jsonip.com/
```

I want ip address in variable for my application. I can get it like that

```
window.onload = function () {
   var script = document.createElement("script");

   script.type = "text/javascript";

   script.src = "https://jsonip.com/?callback=DisplayIP";
   document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
};
function DisplayIP(response) {
   document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + 
   response.ip;     
alert(response.ip);  // alerts  ip address
}
```

I have to use it with Sharpspring forms so the above method can't be integrated with sharpspring code. I want something like that

```
var ip = 'ip address';
```

For your easy understanding, here is the sharpspring form code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ss_form = {'account': 'MzawMDEzNjI0BwA', 'formID': 'SzQ1MTAzSEzSNTG2NNQ1STJN1k1KMjfVNTIzSwbCJKMUS2MA'};
    ss_form.width = '100%';
    ss_form.height = '1000';
    ss_form.domain = 'app-3QNBWW1ZDA.marketingautomation.services';
   ss_form.hidden = {'field_3270188034': 'ip address'}; //here I want to use that ip
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://koi-3QNBWW1ZDA.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=1.1.1"></script>
```

Comment: Where is `ss_form` used later? Is it a hardcoded global variable read by the `koi-...` script?

Comment: ss_form is used in form.js file that is included at the end. it is SS provided code

Comment: Why don't you set the `ss_form.hidden` in the DisplayIP `function`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the script require the use of `document.write`, I don't think it's possible in a single document. Rather, you can fetch the IP on the initial page load, then load the page *again* and synchronously create the `ss_form` object, and inject the `form.js`:

```
if (!sessionStorage.ip) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=DisplayIP";
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  window.DisplayIP = function DisplayIP(response) {
    sessionStorage.ip = response.ip;
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
  }
} else {
  const ip = sessionStorage.ip;
  sessionStorage.removeItem('ip');
  window.ss_form = {
    account: 'MzawMDEzNjI0BwA',
    formID: 'SzQ1MTAzSEzSNTG2NNQ1STJN1k1KMjfVNTIzSwbCJKMUS2MA',
    width: '100%',
    height: '1000',
    domain: 'app-3QNBWW1ZDA.marketingautomation.services',
    hidden: {
      'field_3270188034': ip
    }
  };
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://koi-3QNBWW1ZDA.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=1.1.1';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

(remove the current `form.js` from your HTML)

Comment: form is not displayed by using above code. Form should be displayed and it should have a hidden field with ip address. you can check it on your end also. thanks

Comment: Do you mean the script isn't running, or what? Are there any errors? I don't have access to your development environment, so I can't see what's going on on your end

Comment: code is running. no errors shown. but form is not being displayed. you can test my above form code on your end. it will display a form.

Comment: I see, though there actually is an error: `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`

Comment: I think there's no way to do this asynchronously - you have to get the value you need on one pageload, then initialize another pageload, see edit

Comment: No, if we get ip and use it in hidden field mentioned. it will work. I talked to SS support

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189302/discussion-between-rizwi-and-certainperformance).